# Axios.delete in React: `Error:DELETE chrome-extension://...`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6, axios

I create the chrome extension in React . During request url `delete`, I received an error: `Error: DELETE chrome-extension://ldkflkflkfklfkfksfk/[object%20Object] net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I tried to do the `Get` method earlier. This method works. Also token, url are good.

In tab `network` in `response headers` I have `Provisional headers are shown`

```
delete = (id) => {

    const url = `https://applic.com/api/v1/todos/${id}?expand=createdBy`;
    const token = '12345'; 

    axios.delete({
      url: url,
      headers: { 'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}` }
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(`Deleted: ${id}` );
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(`error: ${id}`);
    });

    const filter = this.state.items.filter(item=> item.id !== id);

    this.setState({ 
      items: filter,
      isOpen: false
    });
}
```

Comment: How stupid of me to ask, still, Does the api support delete request? Can u edit the question with those headers as well.

Comment: @SuryapratapSingh Api support delete request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `axios.delete` is `axios.delete(url[, config])`

The API call should be:

```
axios.delete(
  url,
  { 
     headers: { 'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`
  }
})
```

[Docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosdeleteurl-config)